# Retrieving last month cost of an Azure subscription using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-billing-api

I am trying to retrieve the total cost of a subscription for a given month (let's say last month).

I tried using `ComputeManagementClient` but I always end up with a whole list of usage details, even when I use a filter in the following way :

```
c_client = ConsumptionManagementClient(creds, sub_id)
startDate = '2019-03-01T00:00:00Z'
endDate = '2019-03-31T23:59:59Z'
filt = "usageStart eq {} and usageEnd eq {}".format(startDate, endDate)
result = c_client.usage_details.list(filter=filt)
...
```

What am I doing wrong ? Do I have to iterate through pages and calculate the total cost by myself ?

EDIT : Thanks to @Joy Wang answer, I get further. But now I end up with daily usage details from the current month instead of last month - whereas I am sure that this subscription was running last month. Any idea ?

Comment: Try to use  `properties/usageStart` and `properties/usageEnd` instead of `usageStart` and `usageEnd`, will it work?

Comment: @joywang you should put your comment as answer.

Comment: @GauravMantri Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you should use `properties/usageStart` and `properties/usageEnd` instead of `usageStart` and `usageEnd`.

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-consumption/azure.mgmt.consumption.operations.usagedetailsoperations?view=azure-python#list-expand-none--filter-none--skiptoken-none--top-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-):

[image]

Comment: I think that was indeed a mistake, thanks. But I still have an issue, I end up with usage details on a daily basis from the current month - from `2019-04-01T00:00:00Z` to  `2019-04-01T23:59:59Z` and then  `2019-04-02T00:00:00Z` to  `2019-04-02T23:59:59Z`. (while I can retrieve data from March on the portal - manually). Any idea ?

Comment: @Jul_DW Not sure, may be related to the time zone? I recommend you to post another question to ask it.